# Losing session in MVC .net application after switching users in IE 11

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session, forms-authentication

I have a MVC application using Forms Authentication that allows users to log in as sub accounts. To accomplish this we do the following

```
 FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
 FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(newMember.UserName, true);
  //Set new session variables
```

I then redirect to a new page.  The new page loads properly, with all user session specific data.  However, when I attempt to navigate to another page as this user, it appears my session is gone.

This only happens in IE.

I have seen a issues similar to this, suggesting that the version of .net is not able to find the cookie store for IE browsers.  However the user already has a session and only has a problem when they login as a new user.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I would sniff the response with Fiddler. My guess is that the Set-Cookie header appears twice, first to remove the cookie, then to set it again. If this is so, IE could be confused. What if you remove thr SignOut then and just reissue the cookie?

Comment: Can check around cookies whether getting stored for this application in IE?

Comment: @WiktorZychla,  I tried removing the Signout and it behaved much better.  I was just concerned that not explicitly removing the old cookie would confuse the browser.